# How to pass object in http client GET method?

Tags: php, httpclient, symfony5

I need to pass an object in the URL to fetch data. I put following URL in the postman to execute result.

```
http://my_url/match/?search={"front": {"id": "1000", manufacturer: "Test"}....}
```

But, I am not sure how to pass  that object using CURL in symfony

```
$url = "http://my_url/match?search=";

        $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', $url, [
            'headers' => $this->shopAuth->setHeader(),
            'query' => [
                'search' => $objToPass
            ]
        ]);
```

I tried to pass as `query` but it results something like this: `?search[front][id]=1000&search[front][manufacturer]=Test ........`

Can anybody please help me ?

Comment: now  `search` is a plain text, just parse that json into an object.

Comment: Looks like the `search` query parameter expects JSON. Have you tried simply using `'search' => json_encode($objToPass)`?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array as the 'query' parameter, Symfony's HttpClient will automatically convert it into query parameters with nested keys. If you want to send a JSON object as a query parameter in the URL, you'll need to manually encode it as a JSON string and then decode it on the server-side.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

// Your JSON object to pass
$objToPass = [
    'front' => [
        'id' => '1000',
        'manufacturer' => 'Test'
    ],
    // Add more data here if needed
];

// Encode the object as a JSON string
$jsonString = json_encode($objToPass);

$url = "http://my_url/match?search=" . urlencode($jsonString);

$httpOptions = [
    'headers' => $this->shopAuth->setHeader(),
];

$response = HttpClient::create()->request('GET', $url, $httpOptions);

// Decode the JSON response from the server if needed
$data = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
```

Comment: Why would you create a new `HttpClient`? OP clearly already has an instance available in `$this->httpClient`

Comment: @Phil, I clearly said that This is a reference.. All he need to do is encoding the values using json_encode

Comment: I just found it odd that you went to the effort of reproducing the `$objToPass` object from the JSON but altered other aspects of OP's code. People _will_ blindly copy / paste from Stack Overflow answers without understanding what changes they're potentially making